# Unit testing static class with repository via public property

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In the current WPF application, we need to retrieve a user object on first use and then just keep that user object on hand as the user uses the application.

We'd planned to do this with a static method.

```
public static class UserHelper
{
    public static User CurrentUser { get; set; }
}
```

However, user data is held in a database. So we're going to need to spin up a copy of our repository in this helper class to do the work:

```
public static class UserHelper
{
    public static User CurrentUser { get; set; }
    private static IRepository _rep = new Repository();

    public static void SetUser(string username)
    {
        CurrentUser = _rep.GetUserByName(username);
    }
}
```

That, however, isn't unit testable - you can't pass in a repository to a static class via a constructor. So the easiest solution would seem to be to make `_rep` public (and rename it as `Rep`) - that way you can still leave it as new `Repository()` in the class, but when testing we can do this:

```
[TestMethod] 
public void Assert_SomethingAboutUsers
{
    Mock<IRepository> repMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    repMock.Setup(z => z.GetUserByName(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new User());
    UserHelper.Rep = repMock.Object;

    // make assertions
}
```

But this smells funny to me. I feel there's something a bit awkward about having a repository in a static class at all.

Is it a bad idea? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that in your design the idea of the tasks and functionality of a UserHelper is not clear to you.

If you would describe a UserHelper, would you say that it is only meant to get information from this one-and-only repository, or would you say that a user helper is able to be used with a (possibly small) range of repositories?

**Suppose a UserHelper is only meant to be used with this one-and-only Repository**. In that case, your design is such that it would be a different thingy if it would use a different repository. Therefore it is not correct that your unit test uses its own repository, because the unit test would test something that in your design would be the different thingy.

On the other hand, if you would say that **the UserHelper should be able to work with various repositories**, then why is your class static? If your design is such that a user helper might work with a different repository, could there be more user helpers during one session or could there only be one?

If you would say that your idea about a user helper is such that there could be several user helpers at the same time, then your user helper isn't a singleton and it shouldn't be static.

If you have a limited set of user helpers and know beforehand which user helpers there might be created, consider using a factory where software-users could say: give me the user helper that ..., for instance, a user helper with this id, or with this name, or that uses this repository, or a UserHelper that is perfect for this specific user, etc. anything that will uniquely identify the user helper you want is good enough.

> Google for Factory Design Pattern

However from your description I have the idea that in your design a user helper ought to support various repositories (at least your normal repository and a special unit test repository), but during one session there is only one user helper, called **THE ONE AND ONLY user helper**. This user helper is meant to work with a given repository, at least until ordered to do otherwise.

Whenever your design describes something like **the one and only instance of a class**, quite often people tend to create a static class, while in fact they need a singleton.

> Google for singleton design pattern.

[MSDN about singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

If you think in your eyes, during one session of your program there is only one user helper, and everybody ought to use this one user helper object, the singleton would look like this:

```
public class UserHelper
{
    private static UserHelper theOneAndOnlyInstance = null;
    public static IRepository Repository {get; set;}

    // private constructor, so no one can create an instance
    private UserHelper() {}

    // the function to get the one and only instance
    public static UserHelper TheOneandOnlyUserHelper
    {
        get 
        {
            if (theOneAndOnlyInstance == null)
            {
                theOneAndOnlyInstance = new UserHelper();
            }
            return theOneAndOnlyInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
public void InitializeProgram()
{
    UserHelper.Repository = GetRepository(...);
}

public void MyFunction()
{
    var userHelper = UserHelper.GetInstance()
    userHelper.SetUser(...);
}

public void MyOtherFunction()
{
    UserHelper.GetInstance().Function1();
}
```

Note that the GetInstance function is not thread safe. Stackoverflow has several topics about how to make it thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your classes under test have a static dependency to `UserHelper`. Static utility classes are the arch enemy of unit tests. Especially when they are doing heavy work like reading from databases.

Is there no way you can make `UserHelper` a non-static class and inject it into the dependent instances? This way you could create mocks of `UserHelper` instead.

Apart from that, `UserHelper` is doing two things: it's reading a user from the database *and* holding onto the `User` object in order to provide it to collaborators. Better read the user from the database *outside* of `UserHelper` and just assign it to the `CurrentUser` property.